# For key and value in file json

Tags: python, linux

FILE json

```
{
  "102": "868",
  "103": "8648",
  "104": "868",
  "105": "8468",
  "1026": "8468",
  "107": "8648",
  "108": "85468",
}
```

I want to make a loop for and get the key and value

Comment: What's stopping you?  What specific question do you have?

Comment: That file isn't valid JSON -- it won't parse because of the trailing `,`. And what have you tried / how much do you know already? (Do you know how to iterate over key/value pairs from a standard Python data structure, so the only problem is converting from JSON to a regular Python object? Then ask only about the specific problem you're having with that conversion. Do you *not* know how to iterate over key/value pairs in Python dictionaries? Then focus on that alone without being unnecessarily specific to JSON).

Comment: Looping through key and value is a basic technique available from any tutorial on Python dictionaries (dict).  What you posted is a dict, not JSON.  We expect you to do your own research before posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looool [in python3.7]

```
import json
with open(path_to_your_json_file) as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    for k in d:
        print(k, d[k])
```